# how to create a push button in a table type data block in oracle form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am using Oracle forms 10g to create a custom form, I have created a data block by using data block wizard of type 'TABLE'. Now i want to create a push button which commits all the changes made on the form.

I am unable to do so, as when i create a push button item in the same data block, multiple buttons in coloumn form appear for obvious reasons.

its a simple insert/search form of tabular type. which will search the data and also allow user to insert the record

Could you please help me in achieving that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, putting

```
commit_form;
```

command in a button's `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger is enough to commit all the changes through the form.

Assume you used *Data Block Wizard* for *your table* named `myTable`, and  a block created with `Number Of Records Displayed` as `10`, after that you added a button into that block, namely `bt_cmt` which will appear as `10` buttons tiled vertically, even if with `Number Of Items Displayed` as `0` as default as in the below picture :

[image]

Then,

- it's enough to convert that `0` to `1`, to make the appearance of the
  button single
- or  you may move the button to a block with `Number Of Records Displayed` as `1`.